# Raster format to read with python

Tags: python, raster, file-formats

I currently have a DEM raster stored in an ESRI geodatabase. I've been asked to create a purely python (e.g., no arcpy functions) program that works with the values. Therefore, I need to convert the raster into something that can be read by python as an array. What file format would that be?

(Alternatively, is this a terrible idea and should I argue for sticking with arcpy functions?)

Comment: Hi, are you allowed to use third party libraries like GDAL or PIL?

Comment: If they're open-source and can be easily included with the final python script, then yes :)

Comment: Okay, what are you supposed to do with the file once you've loaded it btw?

Comment: Doing some distance and elevation calculations to build sight lines -- the math isn't particularly hard, as long as I can find out (1) where I am in the array and (2) what the value is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) Pytho API as a substitute for ArcPy, which will give you an extensive range of functions.  If you are using GDAL then you have quite an extensive list of possible formats but GeoTiff is always a popular choice but there are plenty of other options (check the GDAL documentation).

Alternatively, if you don't want to use GDAL, then you will still need some serious array-crunching modules, so [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) spring to mind  (in fact you will probably want these tools even with GDAL).  If you are going down this route you will find it easiest to save your DEM as an image (so again GeoTiff is still a good choice).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MappaGnosis. GeoTiff is a safe choice as GDAL and most other Python image processing library work with it. Aside from GDAL, you can also use [PyRaster](http://www.students.ncl.ac.uk/tom.holderness/software/pyraster/index). It's a collection of Python tools for processing raster data as NumPy arrays. The project site has [examples](http://www.students.ncl.ac.uk/tom.holderness/software/pyraster/examples) which should get your started. Good luck!